# How to retrieve full endpoint URL in Quarkus test?

Tags: quarkus

I am looking a solution to retrieve full endpoint URLs within Quarkus application to use it in tests to avoid hard-coding the paths.

The [official guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing) suggests using the `@TestHTTPEndpoint` and `@TestHTTPResource` annotations.

If I annotate my test class with `@TestHTTPEndpoint(MyResource::class)`, then all calls via RestAssured without specifying the path work just fine. The problem is, when I try to retrieve the endpoint URL like this (let's say, I need to call multiple endpoints in one test):

```
@TestHTTPEndpoint(MyResource::class)
@TestHTTPResource
lateinit var myResourceUrl: URL
```

it kind of works, but the injected URL does not include the `quarkus.http.root-path` value.

Instead of `http://localhost:8081/root-path/my-resource` I get just `http://localhost:8081/my-resource`.

Is there a way to retrieve a full endpoint path that includes the `quarkus.http.root-path` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it seems to be a bug in Quarkus and will be fixed soon.

- [@TestHTTPResource annotation injects endpoint URL without the quarkus.http.root-path segment · Issue #27416 · quarkusio/quarkus · GitHub](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/27416).

As a workaround, one could set the `quarkus.servlet.context-path` property in the `test/resources/application.properties` file like this:

```
quarkus.servlet.context-path=${quarkus.http.root-path}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

Let's consider the following versions as the current versions.

- Quarkus: `2.11.2.Final`.

## Root cause analysis

The `io.quarkus.test.common.http.TestHTTPResourceManager` (`TestHTTPResourceManager` for short) class performs the value injection into the fields annotated with the `io.quarkus.test.common.http.TestHTTPEndpoint` (`TestHTTPEndpoint` for short) annotation:

- The `TestHTTPResourceManager` class retrieves an instance of the `org.eclipse.microprofile.config.Config` (`Config` for short) from the `org.eclipse.microprofile.config.ConfigProvider` (`ConfigProvider` for short) class and uses the `test.url` configuration property value retrieved from the `Config` instance (the `Config.getValue(…)` method call) as **the base URL**.
- The retrieved `test.url` configuration property value seems to correspond to the `test.url` system property value that was provided by the `io.quarkus.test.common.http.TestHTTPConfigSourceProvider` (`TestHTTPConfigSourceProvider` for short) class.

### Possible root cause

For some reason the `TestHTTPConfigSourceProvider` class does not take into account the `quarkus.http.root-path` property value, when providing the `test.url` system property value, which seems to be used as **the base URL**: [quarkus/TestHTTPConfigSourceProvider.java at 2.11.2.Final · quarkusio/quarkus](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/2.11.2.Final/test-framework/common/src/main/java/io/quarkus/test/common/http/TestHTTPConfigSourceProvider.java#L17-L18):

```
    static final String TEST_URL_VALUE = "http://${quarkus.http.host:localhost}:${quarkus.http.test-port:8081}${quarkus.servlet.context-path:}";
    static final String TEST_URL_KEY = "test.url";
```

Therefore, it looks like a Quarkus issue: a defect (a bug) or a lack of a feature (or a lack of the feature implementation).
Therefore, it is worth reporting it as a Quarkus issue.